# Laravel 4 - Validation with Validator in Packages

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Trying to use the Validator class in my Package class. Now with Facades, it's become a bit tricky to include the classes and use them.

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator
...
protected function valid($request)
{
  return Validator::make($request, ['url'=>'required|url'])->passes();
}
```

Ends up giving me:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Validation\Validator::make()

Which is true since I am not using the Facade itself. Looking at the Validator class constructor:

```
__construct(\Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface $translator, array $data, array $rules, array $messages) : void
```

And here's where I need help :)

Comment: any specific reason why you aren't using the facade?

Comment: I do want to use the Facade, actually this is my aim behind this post ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you would like to use the validator facade in your package then change your use to either:

```
use Validator;
```

Or:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```

Or you can inject an instance of the validator factory (which is what actually makes your validator instance) into the class as a dependency. I'm assuming you're setting your package up with a service provider, so something like this.

```
$this->app->bind('Package', function($app)
{
    return new YourPackage($app['validator']);
});
```

You should then set the validator property on that class in the constructor.

```
public function __construct(\Illuminate\Validation\Factory $validator)
{
    $this->validator = $validator;
}
```

You should now be able to make a new validator instance.

```
return $this->validator->make($request, ['url' => 'required|url'])->passes();
```

Comment: I would advice not to use Validator alias since that would only available when application is booted. Use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator or $app['validator']

Comment: I believe this works in a service provider, but what about testing ?

Comment: mocking the validator instance would be a good way of doing unit testing, checkout Mockery

Comment: Just got introduced to the Dependency Injection side of the matter, seems to be the answer to testing.